# ASP.Net How to programmatically add a background image for my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I want to add a background image to my site programmatically however the code I have came upon does not work.

First I use Javascript to print the browsers dimensions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clientScreenWidth").val($(window).width());
    $("#clientScreenHeight").val($(window).height());
});
```

After which I send these dimensions to vb.net via hidden inputs and assign them values:

```
Dim height As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("clientScreenHeight")
Dim width As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("clientScreenWidth")
```

However when I tried to input these arguments into a string and pass it to my body's css there is an error:

```
Dim BackgroundImageURL As String = "https://unsplash.it/" + height + "/" + width
body.Style.Add("background-image: url(""" + BackgroundImageURL + """);")
```

> > Overload resolution failed becuase no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments.

EDIT:

POSTING TO SAY I FIXED THE OVERLOAD RESOLUTION ERROR!

The syntax is "classid.style.add("first part of css name", "second part")"

example: body.style.add("background-image", "url(""http://google.com/logo.png"")")

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for Style.Add, although I'm not sure why you don't do it all in JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it all in JS, hard to believe i overlooked such a simple step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the body style in .NET codebehind, add an ID and runat="server". Then it becomes easier to reference it in .NET.

```
<body id="body1" runat="server">

</body>
```

code behind:

```
Dim BackgroundImageURL As String = "https://unsplash.it/" + height + "/" + width

body1.Attributes["style"] = "background-image: url(\"" + BackgroundImageURL + "\");"
```